# invalid syntax on attempting to create a class that inherits from Python list

Tags: python, list, inheritance

I am creating a small class that inherits from a Python list.

```
class palette(list):

    def __init__(
        self,
        *args,
        name   = None, # string name
        colors = None, # list of colors
        ):
        super().__init__(self, *args)   
        self._name   = name
        self.extend(colors)
```

When I run this, I get a syntax error at the `name` argument of the initialisation function. Why is this? How can I fix it? I am working with both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Are you sure inheritance is what you want here?

Comment: Note that as Ron pointed out, this has nothing to do with initialization... you can't put *args and then have other arguments afterwards (except **kwargs)

Comment: Key-word only argument are only supported in Python 3: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/
i.e `*args` will consume everything in Python 2.
A working patch was available for Python 2.7 but they never committed it: http://bugs.python.org/issue1745 :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*args` must come *after* the other arguments, not before or in the middle of them. (At least in Python 2.)

So this is valid:

```
def myfunc(foo, bar, *args):
    pass
```

but this is not:

```
def myfunc(foo, *args, bar):
    pass
```

--

As @Padraic Cunningham pointed out in the comments, also note that you have a second syntax error: the trailing comma after `colors = None`. And your call to `super()` will fail at run time. You probably want `super(palette, self).__init__(*args)`.

Comment: Actually in Python 3 you can use defaulted keyword args after positional arguments and varying positional arguments.. [See PEP-3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)

Comment: Thanks, added a note to clarify for Python 2.

Comment: Even with that fix it is still going to error, there is a trailing comma and `super().__init__(self, *args)` is not going to work using python2

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks, you're right, I'll add a note about the trailing comma. (Though OP does specify the syntax error after `name`.)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Also, `super().__init__(self, *args)` works fine for me (Python 2.7.8). Something I'm missing?

Comment: You sure you are using python2?

Comment: Positive. But now I see what's happening--I was checking only for syntax errors. But you're right, it raises a `TypeError` when that code is actually executed. Thanks for the tip, answer updated to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

An argument signature like `func(self, *args, name=None, colors=None)` specifies `name` and `colors` as [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).  This is only possible in Python 3.  If you want your code to work with Python 2, you need to move the `*args` to the end of the argument list (and accept that arguments passed positionally will fill in `name` and `colors`).